# Route AWS Route53 email to cpanel email server

Tags: email, dns, cpanel, amazon-route53, mx-record

I recently transferred my domain from GoDaddy to AWS Route53 as I was having trouble with GoDaddy not publishing my DKIM record and all of my outbound emails were ending up in spam.

Now that I have everything transferred to Route53, I would like to still receive emails sent to my domain in the cpanel email client.

I set the mx records in Route53 to:
    0 smtp.secureserver.net
    10 mailstore1.secureserver.net

However, none of the emails that I send to my domain are getting through. I am getting a 'Recipient not found' error.

DNS is obviously not my forte, and any help would be much appreciated.

UPDATE:
  I spoke with someone from cpanel and was told that I need to add an MX record like 0 mail.mydomain.com. But I still need to know what to point to with the alias record for mail.mydomain.com.

Answer (score 3):

So the correct answer was to add an mx record ( 0:mail.mydomain.com ) and create an A record for mail.mydomain.com that pointed to the ip address for the domain on cpanel.